# Status Bar Rotates but UIViewController Does Not

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that rotates as normal when it is first pushed (it's the root view controller of the app's UINavigationController), but will not rotate after the navigation controller pops back to it. The status bar rotates, and shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation: is called (and returns YES), but the view does not rotate and didRotateToInterfaceOrientation: is not called.

Has anyone seen this before or know what might cause it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it also inside a tabbarcontroller?

Comment: No, there is no tab bar controller. The view controller's navigation controller is the root VC of the app's window. Also, small correction to my initial post: rather than popViewControllerAnimated:, I use setViewControllers:animated:. The screen that won't rotate is a login screen, so I didn't think it made much sense to leave it on the navigation stack after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, silly mistake: I pushed the login controller with the line:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[LoginViewController alloc] autorelease],nil] animated:YES];
```

Which omits the init method. I corrected the error and rotation works. Silly me.